# how to remove previous version of bootstrap cdn?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my site unfortunately there are two bootstrap cdn versions,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If simply remove the 2.1.1 version will affect the styles in webpages.So is there any way to remove this version from my website without affecting any styles in my website?

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you don't want the styles to change, then don't change the CSS you are using.

Comment: Actually i need to remove 2.1.1 version?@Quentin

Comment: @akhilviswam — You can't remove it **and** have no effect on the elements it affects. So either remove it and make any other changes you need to keep the page sane, or don't remove it.

Comment: There is massive change in styles because class names have slight difference when it comes to 3.1.1 version.@Quentin

Comment: @akhilviswam — Obviously. It's a major release. It works in different ways. It isn't backwards compatible.